# cuFFT of a matrix as a 1D transformation of rows or columns

Tags: cuda, fft

I could not find an example of application of cuFFT with CUDA in which the transformation of a matrix is realized as 1D transformations of rows and columns.

I have a `2048x2048` array (set as 1D of `cuComplex` data). With 2D transform - no problem. But now what I need is to do the transform along `x`, do some work on it, take inverse fft, then do the transform along `y`, and do another work on it, then take its inverse transform.

How exactly would the sequence of commands look like if I want to use parallel processing? Should I use `cuFFTPlanMany`? How? Or, perhaps, is there an example somewhere that I was not able to find?

Answer (score 3):

In the cuFFT Library User's guide, on page 3, there is an example on how computing a number `BATCH` of one-dimensional DFTs of size `NX`. Using `cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH);`, then `cufftExecC2C` will perform a number `BATCH` 1D FFTs of size `NX`. To achieve that, you have to arrange your data in a complex array of length `BATCH*NX`. In your case, for the transform along `x`, it would be `BATCH=2048` and `NX=2048`. For the transforms along `y`, you have to transpose the matrix arising from previous calculations.

Your code will look like the following

```
#define NX 2048
#define NY 2048

int main() {

    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftComplex *data;
    ...
    cudaMalloc((void**)&data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*NY);
    cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2C, NY);
    ...
    cufftExecC2C(plan, data, data, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    ...
    // do some work
    ...
    // make a transposition
    ...
    cufftPlan1d(&plan, NY, CUFFT_C2C, NX);
    ...
    cufftExecC2C(plan, data, data, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Currently, this approach is deprecated.[cufftMakePlanMany](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#function-cufftmakeplanmany) for multiple transforms should be used.